# sed pattern with multiple words to update

Tags: linux, macos, unix, sed

I want to do something like this, but I'm not sure how.

I want to update the exports.version = '2.0.0' to a new value of exports.version = '2.0.1'

Using:

```
sed -i '.bak' 's/'2.0.0'/'2.0.1'/g' phantomjs.js
```

But this may cause a problem is I have something else with 2.0.0

```
sed -i '.bak' 's/exports.version = '2.0.0'/exports.version = '2.0.1'/g' phantomjs.js
```

In short, how to I feed sed a pattern of exports.version = '2.0.0'

uname -a

15.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.0.0: Sat Sep 19 15:53:46 PDT 2015; root:xnu-3247.10.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Thanks,

L

Comment: "version" or "versions"?

Comment: Fantastic; this worked. As did John1024's response. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -i '.bak' "s/exports\.version = '2\.0\.0'/exports.version = '2.0.1'/g" phantomjs.js
```

Comment: For escaping the `.`: +1.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put single-quotes inside a single-quoted string.  If you do that, you need to enter them like this:

```
$ sed -i .bak 's/exports.version = '\''2.0.0'\''/exports.version = '\''2.0.1'\''/g' phantomjs.js
```

It is not possible to directly put a single-quote inside a single-quoted string.  In the above, `'\''` works because the first single quote ends the preceding single-quoted string, the `\'` puts an escaped single-quote on the command line, and the following `'` starts a new single-quoted string.

In your particular case, you could also use a double-quoted string:

```
sed -i .bak "s/exports.version = '2.0.0'/exports.version = '2.0.1'/g" phantomjs.js
```

This is convenient because it is possible to put single-quotes inside a double-quoted string without any escaping.  This is tricky though because you have to be sure that there are no shell-active characters in the string.  In this case, there aren't, so it happens to be safe.